# TSQL Optimize for multiple nested case query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone help me optimize this query. I only wrote out 2 of the case statements, but it actually has like 30 such cases all nested as seen in this example (with 2) below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM QS
INNER JOIN R ON (CASE 
                    WHEN R.FieldCode = 'L'
                       THEN ---
                CASE 
                    when (
                    (R.Match = 1 AND QS.lineid 
                    IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))
                    OR (R.Match = 0 AND QS.lineid NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))) then 1
                    ELSE 0 
                END
            ----
        WHEN R.FieldCode = 'D'   
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    when ((R.Match = 1 AND QS.productid 
                    IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))
                     OR (R.Match = 0 AND QS.productid NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))) then 1
                    ELSE 0 
                END
END)=1
```

Comment: What is "wrong" with the query that needs to be optimized (slow performance, or just tedious and extremely long)? Perhaps it's best to write a scalar function that takes FieldCode, Match, ProductId, FieldValue, etc so you have all the logic organized logically into a crazy query (and can reuse it)

Comment: THIS IS SUPER SLOW AS IS

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad SQL code, as the database engine cannot do any optimization at all since it needs to enumerate the entire table and go record by record doing multiple tests on each, twice.

You can do this without any CASE at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM QS
INNER JOIN R ON (   (R.FieldCode = 'L'
                     AND (   (R.Match = 1 AND QS.lineid IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))
                          OR (R.Match = 0 AND QS.lineid NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))))
                 OR (R.FieldCode = 'D'
                     AND (   (R.Match = 1 AND QS.productid IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))
                          OR (R.Match = 0 AND QS.productid NOT IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,s) FROM SplitFunc(',', R.FieldValue)))))                 
                )
```

Comment: Are you saying OR is better than a Case statement?  From what I can see that's what you changed here.

Comment: The process the engine uses to treat a join is different. You can see the difference if you look at the query execution plan in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Does this perform better for you? Not knowing the relative row counts or underlying data, I would think this might be much faster and easier to maintain since you don't have to run the scalar function over and over again and should be more optimizer-friendly.

```
SELECT * -- Change to only get fields you need from QS.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        QS.*,
        ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
            CASE R.FieldCode
                WHEN 'L' THEN QA.lineid
                WHEN 'D' THEN QA.productid
                -- ...
                END + ',' AS MatchValue,
        ',' + R.FieldValue + ',' AS FieldValueCSV
        R.Match
    FROM QS 
        CROSS JOIN R
    ) T
WHERE (T.Match = 1 AND T.FieldValueCSV LIKE '%' + T.MatchValue + '%')
    OR (T.Match = 0 AND NOT T.FieldValueCSV LIKE '%' + T.MatchValue + '%')
```